# Repeat AsyncTask if data is not enough

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-volley

I need to make several requests to server to download all data I need. However I never know how many requests to server may be needed. So my first thought was to do it in a loop like so:

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
boolean isDone = false;

do{
    new dataTask().getMyData(new myCallback() {
       // ...some logic here...
    });
}
while(goodItems.size() < 20 || isDone != true);
```

This did not work, because the loop will not wait untill async task is completed in callback and generates a lot of unneeded tasks.

**Question:**
What would be the right way to retry data download until I have all items I need, if I don't know how many times I will need to retry the task?

Comment: put the loop inside the AsyncTask

Comment: You can use Volley library, which has retry policy out of the box. You can set number of retries and interval of retries.

Comment: Also, side note: | is binary OR, you should use || instead for logical OR. I guess that was pseudocode though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a callback for this, nor do you need more than one thread (next to the UI thread).

Put your loop inside the `doInBackground` method:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<Item>> {

     boolean isDone = false;

     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

         ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

         while (goodItems.size() < 20 || isDone != true) {
            // request and adding of items to goodItems
         }

         return goodItems;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> result) {
        // update views
     }
 }
```

Start the AsyncTask like this:

```
new DownloadTask().execute("exampleurl.com/data");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `do-while` loop for this. The cleanliest way could be to re-start the `AsyncTask` inside the `Callback`. Something like this

```
MyCallback cb = new MyCallback(){
 if(goodItems.size() < 20) new DataTask().getMyData(cb);
}
new DataTask().getMyData(cb);
```

Note: Start class names with an upper-letter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a function to do this, and call it again if you're unable to get a response:

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

void fetchItems() {
    new dataTask().getMyData(new myCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(List<Item> items) {
            // some logic here
            if (goodItems.size() < 20 || isDone != true) {
                fetchItems();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just put checking logic and re-doing the request inside your Callback like so:

```
void load() {
    new DataTask().getMyData(new MyCallback() {
        void onComplete(List<Item> items) {
            goodItems.addAll(items);
            if (goodItems.size() < 20) {
                load();
            }
    });
}
```